# pcl visualizer, rendering windows in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, access-violation, point-cloud-library

I have created a class containing a thread of pclvisualizer. see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155658/using-pclvisualization-in-different-threads-from-different-instance-of-a-cla).

and I  have found that the problem arises from the function "Interactor->Render" when you try to refresh the point cloud visualizer windows.

although there is no conflict between threads (no shared data and ...), when two different threads from different objects enter the function "render" this error produced:

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000010.
```

here is the piece of the intractor_style.cpp file, where the error occurs:

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle::OnTimer ()
{
  if (!init_)
  {
    pcl::console::print_error ("[PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle] Interactor style not initialized. Please call Initialize () before continuing.\n");
    return;
  }

  if (!rens_)
  {
    pcl::console::print_error ("[PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle] No renderer collection given! Use SetRendererCollection () before continuing.\n");
    return;
  }
  rens_->Render ();
  Interactor->Render (); /*error occurs here*/
}
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, This problem arises from VTK which is not thread safe. and causes even completely different threads interfere each other, when they are rendering their windows.

Comment: Actually I think you can use experience from other tags, so I added c++ and access violation to the tags.

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?

Comment: This is possible on Linux I think, but impossible on macos, because rendering must always happen on the main thread.