# PCL Visualizer demo interaction customization crashing on spinonce

Tags: multithreading, locking, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to get the PCL Visualizer demo examples to work (all code here: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) for Windows, PCL 1.6, 32 bits version.

It works fine except for the Interaction Customization part, which is ironically the one i'm most interested on. An unhandled exception occurs at the spinOnce(100) line on the main method. From the long search I've done, it looks like it is deeply connected to VTK not being thread safe and keyboard/mouse callbacks interfering with the VTK window. However, I don't think I've completely understood this and could be mistaken. I have found a very similar question here in stackoverflow ([using "pcl::visualization" in different threads from different instance of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155658/using-pclvisualization-in-different-threads-from-different-instance-of-a-cla)) and I tried using scoped_locks around the spinonce, as he suggests, but I think I'm not doing it right.

Has anyone managed to fully use this example on win32? For reference, here is my poor attempt at locking the spinonce:

```
while (!viewer->wasStopped ())
 {

boost::mutex vis_mutex;  //storage for static lock 
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(vis_mutex); 
viewer->spinOnce (); 
boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));

  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it may be related to the version of PCL.

Tutorials are made to match latest versions of PCL and since 1.6 things might have changed.

I recommend you to update to the latest [PCL from github](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl). (actually I use code from this tutorial on win64 right out of the box, no issues)

Comment: Ok, I will try that and report back. Thanks!